# Run linux command in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm trying to do the following..

```
   if "ps | grep -e file" then
      true;
   else
      false;
```

What would I need to do to make the string n the if statement execute the linux command listed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `system("command")`. It'll return true if the command was successfully executed.

**EDIT**
Just read your question again, and I believe that what you're looking for is this:

```
if `ps | grep -e file`.empty? # no matches
  true
else
  false
end
```

Comment: Was about to add that empty? call, please add an end statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have to call `grep`. Just call `ps` and let Ruby find the things you want.

```
if `ps`["file"]
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux ps has a -C switch to check for a specific program name:

```
if "ps -C file" then
   true;
else
   false;
```

however - if you have a construct like

```
if (predicate) then true; else false;
```

it should be the same as

```
(predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Linux Command like this

```
`echo "done"`
```

This will print `done` as output.